# How do I format a currency with commas and 2 decimal places?

Tags: go

I am trying to format some numbers as a currency, with commas and 2 decimal places. I've found "github.com/dustin/go-humanize" for the commas but it doesn't allow for specifying the number of decimal places. fmt.Sprintf will do the currency and decimal formatting but not the commas.

```
for _, fl := range []float64{123456.789, 123456.0, 123456.0100} {
    log.Println(humanize.Commaf(fl))
  }
```

Results:

```
123,456.789
123,456
123,456.01
```

I am expecting:

```
$123,456.79
$123,456.00
$123,456.01
```

Comment: Never ever ever use float's for storing currency, its such a bad idea ! - See http://play.golang.org/p/TQBd4yJe6B

Comment: I have amended my answer to propose an alternative.

Comment: You can checkout the leekchan/accounting project, using Go1.5 big.Float. See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31503800/6309).

Comment: If you want to get the job done without a third party lib, maybe this solution works for you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71142159/10435604

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good blog post about why you should never use floats to represent currency here - http://engineering.shopspring.com/2015/03/03/decimal/

From their examples you can :

```
  d := New(-12345, -3)
  println(d.String())
```

Will give you :

```
-12.345
```

Comment: Link doesn't work, it is available here https://web.archive.org/web/20190518124510/https://engineering.shopspring.com/decimal-an-arbitrary-precision-fixed-point-decimal-library-for-go-ff8b31ca7a5f

Answer (score 12):

That would be what the [humanize.FormatFloat()](https://github.com/dustin/go-humanize/blob/00897f070f09f194c26d65afae734ba4c32404e8/number.go#L52-L65) does:

```
// FormatFloat produces a formatted number as string based on the following user-specified criteria:
// * thousands separator
// * decimal separator
// * decimal precision
```

In your case:

```
FormatFloat("#,###.##", afloat)
```

That being said, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503742/how-do-i-format-a-currency-with-commas-and-2-decimal-places/31503800#comment51011380_31503742) by [LenW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41292/lenw), `float` ([in Go, `float64`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24354495/6309)) is not a good fit for currency.
See [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Using a package like [`go-inf/inf`](https://github.com/go-inf/inf/tree/master) (previously `go/dec`, used for instance in [this currency implementation](https://github.com/fritzpay/paymentd/blob/b3f3fbb80176bc882e6e7ca21b0e56aea81add64/pkg/decimal/decimal.go#L6-L11)) is better.

See [Dec.go](https://github.com/go-inf/inf/blob/c85f1217d51339c0fa3a498cc8b2075de695dae6/dec.go#L35):

```
// A Dec represents a signed arbitrary-precision decimal.
// It is a combination of a sign, an arbitrary-precision integer coefficient
// value, and a signed fixed-precision exponent value.
// The sign and the coefficient value are handled together as a signed value
// and referred to as the unscaled value.
```

That type `Dec` does include [a `Format()` method](https://github.com/go-inf/inf/blob/c85f1217d51339c0fa3a498cc8b2075de695dae6/dec.go#L459-L468).

---

Since July 2015, you now have **[`leekchan/accounting`](https://github.com/leekchan/accounting)** from [Kyoung-chan Lee (`leekchan`)](https://github.com/leekchan) with the same advice:

> Please do not use `float64` to count money. Floats can have errors when you perform operations on them.
> Using [`big.Rat`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Rat) (< Go 1.5) or [`big.Float`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float) (>= Go 1.5) is highly recommended. (accounting supports `float64`, but it is just for convenience.)

```
fmt.Println(ac.FormatMoneyBigFloat(big.NewFloat(123456789.213123))) // "$123,456,789.21"
```

Comment: This seems to be more practical than Commaf that the OP mentioned in https://github.com/dustin/go-humanize/issues/18#issuecomment-122625518

Comment: With the latest version of humanize, you have to remove the '$' symbol, otherwise you will get the error: "invalid positive sign directive".

Answer (score 0):

```
fmt.Printf("%.2f", 12.3456)
```

-- output is 12.34

Comment: it gets the decimals but not the commas

Comment: perhaps FormatFloat("$#,###.##", the_float). I don't have go in front of me